# SceneKit Renderer Function Not Working Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit

I am currently working with Swift 3 and SceneKit. My issue seems to be that my renderer function is not working properly. I don't know what I am doing wrong. The program runs but none of the code in the: `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)`  seems to execute.

Here is my code up to the renderer function.

`import UIKit
    import QuartzCore
    import SceneKit`

`class GameViewController: UIViewController, SCNSceneRendererDelegate`{

```
    let scene = SCNScene()
    let cameraNode = SCNNode()   
    var person = SCNNode()   

    let firstBox = SCNNode()

    var goingLeft = Bool()

    var tempBox = SCNNode()

    var prevBoxNumber = Int()

    var boxNumber = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.createScene()
}


func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {


        let deleteBox = self.scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "\(prevBoxNumber)", recursively: true)


        if (deleteBox?.position.x)! > person.position.x + 1 || (deleteBox?.position.z)! > person.position.z + 1{


            prevBoxNumber += 1
            deleteBox?.removeFromParentNode()
            createBox()


                       }


    }
```

Here is my creatBox() function:

```
   func createBox(){
    tempBox = SCNNode(geometry: firstBox.geometry)
    let previousBox = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "\(boxNumber)", recursively: true)
           boxNumber += 1
    tempBox.name = "\(boxNumber)"


    let randomNumber = arc4random() % 2

    switch randomNumber {
    case 0:
        tempBox.position = SCNVector3Make((previousBox?.position.x)! - firstBox.scale.x, (previousBox?.position.y)! , (previousBox?.position.z)!)
        break
    case 1:
         tempBox.position = SCNVector3Make((previousBox?.position.x)! , (previousBox?.position.y)! , (previousBox?.position.z)! - firstBox.scale.z)
        break
    default:
        break

    }
    self.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(tempBox)
}
```

here is my createScene()

```
 self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    let sceneView = self.view as! SCNView
    boxNumber = 0
    prevBoxNumber = 0
    sceneView.delegate? = self
    sceneView.scene = scene
 //Create Box
    let firstBoxGeo = SCNBox(width: 1, height: 1.5, length: 1, chamferRadius: 0)
    firstBox.geometry = firstBoxGeo
    let boxMaterial = SCNMaterial()
    boxMaterial.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 0.2, green: 0.8, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
    firstBoxGeo.materials = [boxMaterial]
    firstBox.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, 0)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(firstBox)
    firstBox.name = "\(boxNumber)"
    for _ in 0...6 {
        createBox()
    }
```

Please let me know if there is anything I am missing or doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen your `createScene()` method so I'm guessing here :)

Have you added your `GameViewController` as a delegate to your `SCNView` instance?

When you have created your `SCNView`, maybe like this:

```
let scnView = self.view as! SCNView
```

you need to add yourself as delegate, like so:

```
scnView.delegate = self
```

And then you should see your

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)
```

being executed.

#### Edit (after having seen your `createScene()` code)

Try changing:

```
sceneView.delegate? = self
```

to

```
sceneView.delegate = self
```

(omit the `?`)

if I do so I can see that your `renderer` delegate method is invoked twice at least. To make it continue being invoked you can add:

```
sceneView.isPlaying = true
```

somewhere in your `createScene()` method if that is what you are aiming for.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: Yep I have. I added most of my createScene() function so you could see.

Answer (score 0):

OHHH!!!! I feel like such an idiot. I had my `sceneView.delegate = self` as an optional AKA: `sceneView.delegate? = self`

Once I removed the question mark everything worked perfectly. Thanks for your help!